# Turing machine halting problem

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines, halting-problem

I have a question about turing machines and halting problem.

Suppose that we have Atm = {(M,w) where M is a turing machine and w is an input} and
HALTtm = {(M,w) where M is a turing machine halts with an input w}

I want to prove that HALTtm <=m Atm

I've tried some methods but I think they're far from the solution. 
Anyone can give some clues ??

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Comment: What exactly is <=m supposed to mean? I read it as `\leq_m`, but how is that defined?

Answer (score 2):

Well, observe that for all (M,w) in HALTtm, it must be that (M,w) is in Atm.  Then show there exists some (M',w') which is a member of Atm but which does not halt, and so is not in HALTtm.

Comment: The second step isn't necessary. Note that he used "<=" which is presumably intended to mean "subset of *or equal to*".

Comment: I suspect <=m is intended to mean the existence of a [many-one reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction). In that case, what the OP is trying to prove is not true.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the following languages, draw a transition diagram for a Turing Machine that accepts that language.

1. `{aibj | i≠j}`

Answer (score 0):

What is <=m? I think you mean "[many-one reduces to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction)"? In that case, what you're asking for is a total computable function f such that for all strings x,

> x belongs to HALTtm if and only if f(x) belongs to Atm

If such an f existed, we could decide the halting problem : given x, compute f(x) and check if f(x) belongs to Atm (Atm is easily recursive/decidable). But since the halting problem is not decidable, such an f cannot exist. So HALTtm *does not* many-one reduce to Atm.

Answer (score 0):

we can do reduction from ATM to HALTTM
let M2 is a new machine like
On input x 
When run M2 on x
if M2 accepts x then halt and acccept
if M2 rejects then M2 goes for an infinite loop

so there exists a x that not halts M2 so ATm is not in HALTTM